# How can I use Drush to sanitize a database on a remote server?

Tags: database, drush

I'm on Pantheon and I want to run some custom SQL queries to sanitize my dev server.

I have the queries in a file, `custom_sanitize.sqlqueries`.

It looks something like this:

```
UPDATE user__field_useragent SET field_useragent_value = 'Sputnik';
UPDATE node__field_useragent SET field_useragent_value = 'Sputnik';
UPDATE node_revision__field_useragent SET field_useragent_value = 'Sputnik';

TRUNCATE TABLE watchdog;
```

**Goal**

I want to run these queries on a remote server with a single Drush command.

**My Current Workaround**

I connect to the database with [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com), cut and paste the queries in, and run them.

**What I tried**

Based on the [Drush 8 sql-query documentation](http://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/sql/sql-query/), I tried to execute my file like this:

```
drush @alias.dev sql-query --file=custom_sanitize.sqlqueries
```

This fails:

```
failed to open stream: No     [warning]
such file or directory drush.inc:904
```

I assume this is because my local drush calls the remote drush on the server, and the file path is different.

So then I tried to input the content of the file this way:

```
`drush @alias.dev sql-connect` < custom_sanitize.sqlqueries
```

This fails with the following message:

```
-bash: PTY: command not found
```

So then I tried inputting the queries in at the command line:

```
drush @alias.dev sql-query "UPDATE node_revision__field_useragent SET field_useragent_value = 'Sputnik';TRUNCATE TABLE watchdog;"
```

This also fails:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Command not supported as typed.
```

I also tried using `hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize()`, but I couldn't get my hook picked up by the drush on Pantheon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pantheon's terminus can **skip drush**, and pipe SQL directly into a "mysql connection command"

```
echo 'UPDATE users SET pass="12345"' | `terminus connection:info mysite.dev --field=mysql_command`
```

([source)](https://groups.google.com/a/pantheon.io/forum/#!topic/power-users/TdeLcAyX6r4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sql-cli` command for that:

> drush @alias.dev sql-cli < custom_sanitize.sql

Comment: I tried that but i get the following output when sending a `.sql` file with a single line about truncating the watchdog table: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
TRUNCATE TABLE watchdog;

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

TERM environment variable not set.`  On the server, the watchdog table is not truncated.

Comment: can you ssh to the remote? It seems it is rather an ssh problem than drush.

Comment: No `ssh` on Pantheon, alas.

Comment: Then, I guess, you are out of luck, unless there are some instructions special to Pantheon. I have no experience with Pantheon, so I cannot help any further. Did you ask the Pantheon support about that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [db_sanitization Quicksilver example](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/quicksilver-examples/tree/master/db_sanitization), and sanitize automatically every time you pulled the database into your dev environment.

If that doesn't work for you, open a ticket with Pantheon, and I will look at it on Monday (if someone else doesn't help you sooner than that).

Comment: Alas, the example didn't work for me (in Drupal 8).  I opened a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can input the queries one by one:

```
drush @alias.dev sql-query "TRUNCATE table watchdog"
```

So, you can change every query in `custom_sanitize.sqlqueries` to be `drush @alias.dev sql-query "myquery"`, and then execute that file.